# Simple counting down code cant count down

Tags: c++

char x;

```
cout << "\n/something?(y/n): ";
cin >> x;

if(x=='y'){
    int n2 = 0;
    cout << "number: ";
    cin >> n2;
    int i = n2;
    for(int i; 0<i; i--){
        cout << i;
    }

    
}
else{
    system("pause");
}
```

How come when I run the code it doesn't count down from the number the user gave?

Comment: Are you getting any warning messages from your compiler? I would expect every modern C++ compiler to tell you exactly where the bug is, here.

Comment: Try to replace int i by i in your loop declaration

Comment: Where you have written `for(int i; 0<i; i--)`,exactly what do you think this means? Try to explain every part of this line, in plain English words. Either you will see the problem immediately, or someone can clarify your misconception.

Answer (score 3):

What is happening here is that you declare local variable `i` in the block which contains for loop, and then declare **another** local variable `i` in the loop itself, and the one in the loop is not initialized. It gets some "trash" value, from each it counts down. I assume you wanted to use `i` declated above the loop in the loop, but it is done differently. To fix this I suggest 2 most reasonable variants:

variant 1 - use `i` declared above the loop

```cpp
int i = n2; 
for(; i>0; i--) {
...
```

variant 2 - use loop-local `i`:

```cpp
// just this, do not declare i above the loop 
for(int i = n2; i>0; i--) {
```